# Difference between running java -cp and implementing a classloader

Tags: java, jvm, classpath, classloader

I would like to know whether there's any functional difference between running my Java app with the -cp command line switch (supplying a folder or a list of jars), and implementing a class loader (for example, using the URLClassLoader class) to load classes.

Example code:

```
// -cp approach
java -jar <myjar.jar> -cp ~/folder/with/jars
```

The other approach:

```
// URLClassLoader approach. urls is an array that points to the .jars under ~/folder/with/jars
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
loader.findClass(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one, using a class loader as in your example would mean hardcoding paths in the source, unlike with `-cp`.

Plus you'd be in charge of loading the classes yourself instead of letting the jvm resolve them. Looks like a lot of unnecessary extra code to me unless there's a good reason to do that.

Another difference (and advantage of a class loader) is being able to load them on demand.

Comment: "hardcoding paths" - suppose these are supplied as a command line argument to the program. Then they are not hard coded. Will that make any functional difference? (by that, i mean - will the program be able to load the same class in both cases, supposed that the URLs available to it are the same).

Comment: Oh, short sight on my part :P I don't think so. Once the classes are loaded, it'd be the same.

Answer (score 1):

In my OpenJDK 7, the system `ClassLoader` is an instance of `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader` which in turn is a subclass of `URLClassLoader` being created with the files from the system property `java.class.path`.

As you can see, in my environment, there seems not to be important functional differences, although there are differences (like the fact that this `AppClassLoader` is registered as "parallel capable" with `ClassLoader.registerAsParallelCapable()`, see `ClassLoader` javadoc).

Since Java is portable, I guess that other implementations of the JVMs might use similar mechanisms. So it looks to me that there won't be important functional differences. Maybe differences in the default permissions policy, extensions, etc. which I wouldn't consider functional.